# Neo4j multiple node labels and performance

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

According to my Spring Data Neo4j 4(SDN4) class hierarchy I have a lot of Neo4j nodes with ~7 labels per each node.

Should I worry about the performance of my application with such number of labels per node or Neo4j labels( and theirs usage in SDN 4) don't impact the performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind every label is an index. So a high number of labels per node will increase the write time for any such node. If you're doing mass updates this will be noticable but for a regular application you will hardly notice the difference on writes. For reads it makes no difference.

Hope this helps,
Tom